# Can a company charge two different prices for the same product at the same time?

Tags: consumer-protection, commerce

Let’s say the company is called X.

I have found out that there are two different links on X’s website which leads to the same product, one that has a price of $1000 and the other $800. The link for the lower price is very hard to find even though it is on the same website.

I called the company today and told them about the problem and they said that they are going to fix it.

However, I have found out that this has been going on for months. So this just means that X has been overcharging thousands of costumers for more than 3 months.

What should I do?

Comment: You do nothing. The company didn't do anything illegal. You didn't get scammed, no one got scammed. Paying a higher price than you should have isn't illegal, as long as you agree to that price

Comment: Coupons are also legal: some people, those who find a coupon, get a lower price. Clearly, coupons are not illegal. There is absolutely no law requiring a price to be uniform for all customers.

Comment: @user6726 Please keep in mind that just because something is commonly practiced without punishment doesn't mean it's not illegal. I am not claiming you are wrong, just that your reasoning is flawed.

Comment: I'm not trying to reason to a conclusion about prices, I'm pointing out that the question is based on an absurd and false premise. For example, I could ask "I saw a man walking down the street talking on a cell phone. What should I do", but that is based on a legally absurd premise.

Answer (score 4):

A company can charge *each* of its customers a different price if it wishes. Providing this discrimination is *not* on the basis of a prohibited reason (race, sex etc.) this is not illegal.

Comment: Is charging by country discrimination?

Comment: Yes - but its not unlawful discrimination.

Answer (score -2):

You tell as many folks as you can to avoid this company if you're so inclined, or do what you can to let them know this company is abusive/engages in manipulative practices. There is no reason other than greed to do such a thing and since greed is protected in general, it's up to the customers to apply pressure, even if that means to never buy something from there again if possible. And then if you are in a region that has it, vote to upend nonsense like that - I'm personally exhausted from having to be price gouged by the same companies we bail out every few years.

Comment: -1 Such a practice is niot in wnwreal abuive, nor in general "reedy".